# Can we make QTableWidget to smooth scroll its content?

Tags: qt, scroll, smooth-scrolling, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget displayed rows with different height. It cause the scrolling behaviour looks jumpy. I think even if all the rows were in the same height, the scrolling is also not smooth.

Haven't found an answer to this issue (or maybe it was just a bad google day). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`tableWidget->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);`

The same goes for horizontal scroll mode.

If you're using QDesigner (or the one built in QtCreator), you can set this property on the QTableWidget in its properties.